# Clean dialog collector class for use in all other activities [Android]

Tags: android, class, dialog, code-cleanup

Im trying and searching for a good method to handle dialogs in a single class so i can use them in any activity i want. The most clean and good performance method would be best.
Currently im handly dialogs in each activity where the main work is done. If i need to change a dialog or dialogevent its a hassle to search through all my classes.

**[SOLVED]** ~ *Update with code below.*

Looks great. Hope im doing good with it. Any optimization?

--- **Code from Dialog Class**

```
public class Dialogs extends Activity {
    public static final int DIALOG_START = 0;
    public static final int DIALOG_END = 1;

    private Context mContext;
    private int mDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        mDialog = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("dialog");
        showDialog(mDialog);
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Dialog dialog = null;
        switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_START:
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Test...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish(); //works because toasts are somehow delayed
            break;
        case DIALOG_END:
            // do something else but always finish(), e.g. after dialogbutton- click.
            break;
        }
        return dialog;
    }

}
```

--- **Code in target Activity (for example button click):**

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent();
dialogIntent.setClass(Main.this, Dialogs.class);
dialogIntent.putExtra("dialog" , Dialogs.DIALOG_START);
startActivityForResult(dialogIntent, 0x0);
```

--- **Code in Manifest:**

```
<activity android:name=".Dialogs" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:theme="@style/dialog" />
```

--- **Code in Stylefile (values/style.xml):**

```
<style name="dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create one Activity whose theme set as `@android:style/Theme.Dialog` in `Android-manifest.xml`. Then you can use this one as dialog(or popup) anywhere simply as we use activities that is by `startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)`.